# Textarea height Chrome problem

Tags: css, google-chrome, textarea, height

Is anyone have solution for textarea height problem in Chrome?

In simple case like this:

```
<div>
    <textarea>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Google Chrome add two pixels, so div.height = textarea.height + 2px. And yes, I try Eric's "reset.ccs" — didn't work.

P.S. of course in my "simple case" textarea and div have border, padding and margin 0px.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because `textarea` is a replaced inline element.

```
textarea {
    display:block;
}
```

should solve your "problem".

Comment: This finally ensures the same textarea height across Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I think the additional margin underneath the `textarea` is due to leaving space for text descenders. For example, you can also set `line-height`/`font-size` on the parent to increase/decrease it, or `vertical-align` on the `textarea`.

Comment: @Ben J yep, `vertical-align` `top` or `bottom` would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The `2px` is the standard border size. It's the same across all browsers though.

This works in Chrome, Firefox..

No borders : http://jsfiddle.net/NctDT/2/

Borders and ajusted `div` height : http://jsfiddle.net/NctDT/4/

In both cases the `div` and `textarea` are both perfectly aligned in height.

Comment: thanks, actually, it was my fault and MatTheCat's answer help me

Comment: You misunderstood the problem slightly. Here's your first demo with a `height` on only `textarea`, check it in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/NctDT/5/

Comment: Well, then you add `textarea {display:block;}` .) +1 for MatTheCat

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, But adding
        `html,body{
        height:100%;
        }`

really seems to work